# Postscript distill error after removing "eexec"

Tags: security, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to distill a postscript file that I created. After I open the .ps file in notepad and remove "mark currentfile eexec...cleartomark" and use the Adobe distiller, I get the error message:

%%[ Error: undefined; OffendingCommand: ï»¿ ]%% %%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%% %%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Use Notepad++ and not Notepad. Notepad changes things as I saved the edited .ps. Then used ghostscript to render the pdf.